# Discord.py Slash commands mandatory parameters, not optionals

Tags: python, parameters, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a simple commands that if you don't enter 2 numbers as arguments, it selects a random number between 1 and 10, the problem is that I want to be needed 2 parameters and not being optional, If you put it it works fine:
[image]

But because neither of the 2 parameters are mandatory, you can write only 1 which makes it work not how I want, this will result in showing the number you choose instead of a random between 2 numbers:

[image]

Here is the code if needed:

```
#COMANDO SLASH NUM
@cog_ext.cog_slash(name='Numero', description='Selecciona un numero aleatorio entre el 1 y el 10 si no se especifica ninguno')
async def numero(self, ctx, primero=1, ultimo=10):
    n = random.randint(int(primero),int(ultimo))
    await ctx.send(n)
```

Comment: Replace your method definition with `async def numero(self, ctx, primero: int, ultimo: int):`

Using `=1` & `=10` has made you app_command parameters optional.

Comment: @Paul But I want that if you don't enter any parameter to be a default one like primero=1 and ultimo=1 is that possible or do I have to choose one, having default values or making it mandatory to set ones?

Comment: You can keep your parameters optional, and add a condition bellow your method definition.
`async def numero(self, ctx, primero: int = None, ultimo: int = None):`
Then bellow your condition: `if not primero or not ultimo: primero, ultimo = 1, 10`
If the condition doesn't match your requirements change `or` to `and`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead

```py
@cog_ext.cog_slash(name='Numero', description='Selecciona un numero aleatorio entre el 1 y el 10 si no se especifica ninguno')
async def numero(self, ctx, primero: int = 1, ultimo: int = 10):
    n = random.randint(primero, ultimo)
    await ctx.send(n)
```

The snipped above accepts integers and defaults the arguments to the number provided after the "=" symbol.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `app_commands.Range` to set the minimum and max values, while still making them required.

```
@cog_ext.cog_slash(name='Numero', description='Selecciona un numero aleatorio entre el 1 y el 10 si no se especifica ninguno')
async def numero(self, ctx, primero:app_commands.Range[int, 1], ultimo:app_commands.Range[int, None, 10]):
    n = random.randint(int(primero),int(ultimo))
    await ctx.send(n)
```